# C implementation of cp

Tags: c, cp

This is a primitive implementation of cp, i compiled and ran it on Linux machine(Ubuntu), this code works fine for text files of any size but not for pdfs or mp3, i dont know what im dong wrong. Is it wrong the way i use EOF? It compiles and runs without error, but does not work for every kind of file.

```
 #include<stdio.h>
 #include<stdlib.h>
 #include <string.h>

 #define MAX_SIZE 2
 #define MAX_BUF_SIZE 256

 int main(int argc, char* argv[])
 {
  FILE *pFile_src=NULL;
  FILE *pFile_dest=NULL;

  char* mychar;
  char *SRC, *DEST;
  int i=0,j;

  char char_buff[MAX_BUF_SIZE];
  mychar= (char *)malloc(sizeof(char *));

  if(argv[1]!=NULL)
      SRC=argv[1];
  else
      printf("\nUSAGE: ./Ex_ManualCP_prog src_file dest_file.\nFirst arg should be a filename, cannot be empty.\n");

  if(argv[2]!=NULL)
      DEST=argv[2];
  else
      printf("\nSecond arg should be a filename, cannot be empty.\n");

  mychar= (char *)malloc(MAX_SIZE*sizeof(char *));

  //initialize text buffer
  for(j=0;j<MAX_BUF_SIZE;j++)
      char_buff[j]='\0';

  pFile_src=fopen(SRC,"r");     //Open file to read and store in a character buffer

  pFile_dest=fopen(DEST,"w");  //open destination file

  if(pFile_dest==NULL)
      printf("\nFile specified as Destination DOES NOT EXIST.\n");

  if(pFile_src==NULL)
      printf("\nFile specified as Source, DOES NOT EXIST.\n");
  else
  {
   //printf("\n----File opened successfully-----\n");

       while(((*mychar=fgetc(pFile_src))!=EOF))
       {
             if(i>=MAX_BUF_SIZE)
             {
                i=0;
             }

             char_buff[i]=*mychar;
             fputc(char_buff[i],pFile_dest); //write buffer data into opened file
             ++i;
        }

       char_buff[i]='\0';
       fclose(pFile_src);  //close source file

   }

   fclose(pFile_dest);

   if(pFile_src!=NULL && pFile_dest!=NULL)
       printf("\n\n-----Copy Done!----\n-----Reached end of file.-----\n");

return 0;
}
```

Comment: open file with the flag for reading: "rb", and writing: "wb", this should solve the problem.

Comment: The flag "b" should have no effect according to fopen's man page.

Comment: @sonukumar Thanks, but, it did not change a thing.

Comment: @Jerry can you please point to the man page which says about flag "b" ?

Comment: @sonukumar, I am on OS X, and the BSD man page is dated January 26, 2003.  What system are you on?

Comment: mac OS X and RHEL

Comment: Can you try to linux system?

Comment: Unix/Linux does not need this Windows legacy.

Comment: @Olaf I'm not sure what's wrong here, I wrote simple CPython script to copy a file it works lie charm, for all format.

Comment: @sonukumar: 1) Python is a programming language, not just a scripting language. 2) CPython is **one** implementation of the Python language. 3) This is not about Python, but C. A very different language! 4) Read what text mode actually is for. Hint: it is ignored by modern OSes. For current desktop systems, only Windows treats it special.

Comment: You have two buffers but you're trying to copy char by char? Things are really not clear in `while` loop. Can you explain us what you try to do in it?

Comment: I think you cannot open a pdf or mp3 files using fopen. The cp command in linux uses open(), read(), write() system calls to perform the operation. You can check the source code of cp command to know more

Comment: @HardikSanghvi actually you can and i did it :)

Comment: @purplepsycho actually, it was my method of implementation, i wanted to read every single character and save it in a character buffer (256 bytes long in this case) like a cache, and put it using `fputc` one after the other in the opened destination file.

Comment: The `mychar= (char *)malloc(sizeof(char *));` line makes absolutely no sense at all, and gives off a scent of a programmer who is very uncertain about pointers.

Comment: @unwind why is it wrong to initialize mychar with a non-garbage value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it wrong the way i use EOF?

It is wrong. `EOF` is of type `int`. The return value of `fgetc` is also of type `int`. You store the value in a `char`.

Your code will fail if the file contains any byte with the value `-1`/`255`. Text files won't, of course, but large binary files are likely to contain such bytes.

Changing the type of `mychar` to `int` will fix that problem.

Another bug is the possible buffer overflow when you `NUL`-terminate `char_buff`. If the file is an even multiple of 256 then `i` will be 
`256` when you add the `NUL`-terminator and you will write outside the buffer.

Comment: Thank you so much, i changed `mychar` to int and did a typecast when i accepted it as a character in `char_buf`  array. i oversaw the return type of `fgetc`. aweswome!